# Is it possible to create an add-on on AMO that targets both desktop and mobile versions of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have developed a Firefox add-on that includes the following snippet in `install.rdf`:

```
<!-- Firefox -->
<em:targetApplication>
  <Description>
    <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
    <em:minVersion>10.0</em:minVersion>
    <em:maxVersion>25.*</em:maxVersion>
  </Description>
</em:targetApplication>

<!-- Firefox Mobile -->
<em:targetApplication>
  <Description>
    <em:id>{aa3c5121-dab2-40e2-81ca-7ea25febc110}</em:id>
    <em:minVersion>10.0</em:minVersion>
    <em:maxVersion>25.*</em:maxVersion>
  </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

The add-on has been tested on both desktop and mobile versions of Firefox and I would like to upload the add-on to [AMO](http://addons.mozilla.org).

However, I can't seem to select both desktop and mobile platforms when uploading the XPI:

[image]

Why am I getting this error and how can I avoid it while still using a single listing for all platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first release of the native version of Firefox Mobile was 14.0. Prior versions, which did not use the native UI, used a different em:id. On my own add-on in the "Update Compatibility" screen on AMO, 10.0a1 is listed, 10.0 is not.

I recommend updating your minVersion to 14.0 as this is the first real, released version. It's very unlikely anyone is going to be using a native version prior to that.

Comment: Thanks! After changing the minVersion to 14.0, I was able to include "All Mobile Platforms."